# Where is the "mistake in the recursion" while there is no recursion?

Tags: products

So my code is as follows

```
xi = Exp[2*Pi I/13]
tauA = xi + xi^(-1)
sigma[tau_, n_] := tau^n
Product[(x - sigma[tauA, i]), {i, 3, 8}] // FullSimplify
```

This should just be a simple calculation but somehow Mathematica is complaining about a Recursionlimit of `Var[x]`, a function which is not even in the code. Does anyone see where the recursion is? Oh, and the resulting polynomial should be $-1 + 3 x + 6 x^2 - 4 x^3 - 5 x^4 + x^5 + x^6$ but it gives me a fully factorised polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$. How can I restrict it to $\mathbb{Z}$ such that the polynomial's coefficients are only integers?

Comment: I'm gonna to out on a limb and say you have a lingering definition. Try `Clear[xi, tauA, sigma]` and give it another go.

Comment: It works fine for me in a fresh kernel. I suspect you have a previous definition of some symbol causing confusion.

Comment: @JohnDoty I did quit the kernel a few times and the clearing did it's job but it somehow keeps running...

Comment: The last line takes awhile. The result is more complicated than you expect.

Comment: @JohnDoty Yes, after a long wait, it is there. But I was hoping to get an answer in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and not a polynomial fully factorised over $\mathbb{C}$. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can use `Collect` to make your power series, and `RootReduce` to (somewhat) simplify the coefficients. They are, however, rather messy algebraic numbers, not the integers you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code returns the polynomial you expected.

```
xi = Exp[2*Pi*I/13];
sigma[t_, n_] := t^n + 1/t^n;
Product[(x - sigma[xi, i]), {i, 6}]//Expand//N//Rationalize
(* -1 + 3*x + 6*x^2 - 4*x^3 - 5*x^4 + x^5 + x^6 *)
```

The `Expand[]` is to multiply out the linear factors into a polynomial. The `N[]` is to get numerical approximation to the coefficients of the polynomial. The `Rationalize[]` is to get a close rational approximation to the coefficients which in this case turn out to be integers.

Comment: This is a different polynomial than the OP presents in the question.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The problem why I didn't take the product up to 6 is because it should be a product  of six elements in $\{-1,1\}-\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. I just want to say that mathematically I don't know why the right polynomial pops out by this product indices, but that must be some coincidence since six elements from $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ is half of it... Don't know, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Algebear Note that `sigma` here is even more significantly different than yours.  In particular, `sigma[t, n] == sigma[t, 13-n]`, so to get the distinct roots, you cannot just take any six nonzero residues modulo 13. But my point is that this does not answer the question as you actually asked it, and a good answer would have explained that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [@John Doty's approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197556/where-is-the-mistake-in-the-recursion-while-there-is-no-recursion/197560?noredirect=1#comment511922_197556) applied to the apparently corrected problem statement judging from the accepted answer:

```
xi = Exp[2*Pi*I/13];
sigma[t_, n_] := t^n + 1/t^n;  (* Note the change: 
Collect[Product[(x - sigma[xi, i]), {i, 6}], x, RootReduce]
```

> $x^6+x^5-5 x^4-4 x^3+6 x^2+3 x-1$

Comment: Both your answer and @Somos 's answer give the right output or "the desired output". The math behind it I'm about to find out.

Comment: @Algebear  Apparently the mistake is that `tauA^n`, which equals `(xi + xi^(-1))^n`, is not the same as `xi^n + xi^(-n)`.  It seem you wanted the latter, if @Somos's answer is correct.